# How to find variable Unique Combinations in 2 sets of numbers/ values

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

For e.g i have 5 Sets with 4 Music tracks in each set like represented below

S1 = [T1,T2,T3,T4]
S2 = [T1,T2,T3,T4]
S3 = [T1,T2,T3,T4]
S4 = [T1,T2,T3,T4]
S5 = [T1,T2,T3,T4]

Case 1:
At any time only one track from one set will be played.
Atleast one track will be played from each set.
i.e. one combination will consist on 5 tracks each from different set

So with above conditions applicable, i want to find how many unique combinations of tracks i have in total.
For e.g. some unquie combinations are .

Comination1  = s1t1 + s2t1 + s3t1 + s4t1 + s5t1 .
Comination2  = s1t2 + s2t2 + s3t2 + s4t2 + s5t2 .
Comination3  = s1t3 + s2t3 + s3t3 + s4t3 + s5t4 .

How is this calculated mathematically?

Further i would also want to calculate some variations.
Case 2:
The combination set can also be of minimun 3 tracks to maximum 4 tracks unlike the earlier fixed 5 tracks.
Each track from the set should be from different set
for e.g.

Comb 1 = s1t1 + s2t1 + s3t1 .
Comb 2 = s2t1 + s3t1 + s4t1 .
Comb 3  = s1t1 + s2t1 + s3t1 + s4t1 .
Comb 4  = s2t1 + s3t1 + s4t1 + s5t1

So How many more combination tracks are available and how to calculate it.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the number of tracks in set $i$ is given by $n_i$ where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $S$. Then the total number of combinations equals $n_1 \cdot n_2 \cdot \cdot \cdot n_S$.

Comment: Hi Srikant.  Can you please give me the value that would be evaluated for case 1 and how was that calculated. I am not good enough in maths and understanding equations.